# VPN restart via command line in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, vpn

How do I start (or restart) my vpn connection from the command line in Ubuntu 11.10?

Thank you!

Comment: Should be moved to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: There are lots of Ubuntu questions on StackOverflow.  Why is this question less appropriate in this forum?  Stackoverflow has been an excellent for quick responsiveness.

Comment: Of course there are a lot ubuntu questions here on SO, because  askubuntu.com is younger than SO. But SO is "a programming Q & A"-site and your question doesn't fit here but is better suited for AU. No offense against you or your question.

Comment: As you can see from the answers below, this question does indeed involve programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a script in this thread that works:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=800330

While the script from Cabalbl4 works fine, isn't there a simpler way to start VPN from the command line?

Anyway, it works!

Answer (score -2):

Please find below a script i've just designed to solve VPN issues : http://pastebin.com/9nixnwRc

Comment: What is TRENDnet658?  And what uuid is id=4b76f318-0985-4989-9135-0c7257b48809?  Thanks.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if the script was pasted here instead of on pastebin.